# After transaction, how to display Transaction ID?

Tags: lucid

After signing a transaction (using Lucid), how can i display the transaction id?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I figured it out.

// Display success message with transaction ID as a link
const transactionLink = 'https://cardanoscan.io/transaction/' + txHash;
successMessageDiv.innerHTML = 'Success! Transaction ID: ' + txHash + '';